# How to make fields mandatory in SWT dialogue?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to design a password dialogue box using SWT and I am able to achieve this using below code but I also want to make both the fields mandatory and I am not able to understand how to include this functionality in below code. Please help me.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class PasswordDialog extends Dialog {
    private Text txtUser;
    private Text txtPassword;
    private String user = "";
    private String password = "";

    public PasswordDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
        layout.marginRight = 5;
        layout.marginLeft = 10;
        container.setLayout(layout);

        Label lblUser = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        lblUser.setText("User:");

        txtUser = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
        txtUser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        txtUser.setText(user);
        txtUser.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                Text textWidget = (Text) e.getSource();
                String userText = textWidget.getText();
                user = userText;
            }
        });

        Label lblPassword = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        GridData gd_lblNewLabel = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
        gd_lblNewLabel.horizontalIndent = 1;
        lblPassword.setLayoutData(gd_lblNewLabel);
        lblPassword.setText("Password:");

        txtPassword = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER| SWT.PASSWORD);
        txtPassword.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        txtPassword.setText(password);
        txtPassword.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                Text textWidget = (Text) e.getSource();
                String passwordText = textWidget.getText();
                password = passwordText;
            }
        });
        return container;
    }

    // override method to use "Login" as label for the OK button
    @Override
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, "Login", true);
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Point getInitialSize() {
         return new Point(450, 300);
    }

    @Override
    protected void okPressed() {
        user = txtUser.getText();
        password = txtPassword.getText();
        super.okPressed();
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can't you just validate when `okPressed` is invoked?

Comment: Please supply a minimal example and further specify your question, this is too broad. Also, documenting your code makes it easier to read and understand. If someone has to break his head to understand a question, you're not likely to get an answer. Oh and please properly format your code,  which also helps readability!

Comment: I think you could spare your okPressed() method as your ModifyListeners already do the job. Or alternatively, you could remove the = "" initializations. A bit less code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `modifyText` listeners you can enable / disable the OK button. Use something like:

```
void updateOKStatus(boolean enable)
{
  Button ok = getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID);
  if (ok != null)
    ok.setEnabled(enable);
}
```